# while loop integer expression expected

Tags: shell, unix, while-loop

I have a problem with this while loop. I want the user to pick one of the three options. I get the error "integer expression expected". When i remove the last option "$UCHOICE" -ne "q", the program works until i type a letter, and i get the same "integer expression expected". I am guessing that the problem has to do with integers and strings but i have no clue. please help.

```
while [ "$UCHOICE" -ne "1" -a "$UCHOICE" -ne "2" -a "$UCHOICE" -ne "q" ]
do
echo "hello"
read UCHOICE
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be using != for [string comparison](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

```
while [ "$UCHOICE" != "1" -a "$UCHOICE" != "2" -a "$UCHOICE" != "q" ]
do
echo "hello"
read UCHOICE
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following message will help you:

**stringA != stringB** stringA does not match stringB

**exprA -ne exprB** Arithmetic expressions exprA and exprB are not equal